# Parse Json, error in the executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to execute a javascript request:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=" + client_id + "&count=12";
    s.addEventListener( 'load', function(){ s.parentNode.removeChild(s); } );
    (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);

    console.log(s);
```

The console print:

```
 <script src="https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=myclientid&count=12"></script>
```

And this url, return me the json, is possible excecute this request?

Comment: If that URL returns JSON, then what you're doing will not work.

Comment: If you're including _JSON_ like this, look to see if there is a _JSONP_ version. Otherwise you'll have to do a cross domain _Ajax_ request.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can '$.getJSON( $(s).attr('src') );' if your 's' variable contains a valid json url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And this url returns me json, is possible excecute this request?

The request is made, but when you attempt to execute a JSON file like a script it will fail with an error message. You are not allowed to access it either, because of the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You would need to make the api respond with a [JSONP script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to let your snippet work. Check instagram's documentation on this.